# Why is the amended element not showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using Knockout and jQuery to try and add a new template to a modal. I have added a function that adds the template to the modal onclick, and it shows it being added to the page correctly, but the template is not rendering to the page. I don't understand what I am doing wrong in this case, is it not rendering because it is a template, is there a better way to do it with a 'click:' ?

HTML

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    </div>

    <script type="text/html" id="person-template">
        <div class = "col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class = "portfolio">
                    <img class="img-responsive rounded" data-bind="attr: {src : src}">
                    <div class= "over-text" data-bind="text: name"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/html" id="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close" onclick= "closeModal()">&times;</span>
                <img class="img-responsive rounded imgModal" data-bind="attr: {src : src}">
                <h3 data-bind="text:name"></h3>
                <p data-bind="text:des"></p>
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: url}">View on GitHub</a>
            </div>
    </script>
```

JS

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName(".close");

function closeModal(){
  modal.style.display = "none";
  while (modal.firstChild) {
    modal.removeChild(modal.firstChild);
  }

}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
      while (modal.firstChild) {
        modal.removeChild(modal.firstChild);
      }
    }
}

function finalPopup(popup){
  var projects = ["memory", "arcade", "pixel", "feed", "map"];
  console.log(projects[popup]);
  var elem = $("<div class=\'innerModal\' data-bind=\"template: { name: \'modal\', data: "+projects[popup]+"}\"></div>");
  $("#myModal").append(elem);
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

function MyViewModel() {
         this.memory = { name: 'Memory', url: ko.observable("https://github.com/jtvkw2/Memory"), src: ko.observable("img/Memory.png"), des: "Built a complete browser-based card matching game (also known as Concentration). But this isn’t just any memory game! It’s a shnazzy, well-designed, feature-packed memory game!"};
         this.arcade = { name: 'Bug Boy in Water World', url: ko.observable("https://github.com/jtvkw2/Bug_Boy_in_Water_World"), src: ko.observable("img/Arcade.png"), des: "An HTML5 Canvas powered video game, developed using the best practices in Object Oriented JavaScript."};
         this.pixel = { name: 'Pixel Maker', url: ko.observable("https://github.com/jtvkw2/Pixel"), src: ko.observable("img/Pixel.png"), des: "Created a single-page app in JavaScript where the user can create artistic designs!" };
         this.feed = { name: 'Feed Reader', url: ko.observable("https://github.com/jtvkw2/Feed-Reader"), src: ko.observable("img/Feed.png"), des: "Wrote comprehensive unit tests, using the Jasmine testing framework, for an RSS Feed Reader application that uses Google's RSS API." };
         this.map = { name: 'Google Maps Demo', url: ko.observable("https://github.com/jtvkw2/Map"), src: ko.observable("img/Map.png"), des: "A single-page web application, built using the Knockout framework, that displays a Google Map of an area and various points of interest. Users can search all included landmarks and, when selected, additional information about a landmark is presented from the FourSquare and Wikipedia APIs." };
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to make the modal part of your Knockout app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you still need to make knockout aware of the new bindings once they're appended to your modal element. Try adding an "applyBindingsToNode" at the end of the popup function.

```
function finalPopup(popup){
  var projects = ["memory", "arcade", "pixel", "feed", "map"];
  console.log(projects[popup]);
  var elem = $("<div class=\'innerModal\' data-bind=\"template: { name: \'modal\', data: "+projects[popup]+"}\"></div>");
  $("#myModal").append(elem);
  modal.style.display = "block";

  ko.applyBindingsToNode(elem[0]);
}
```

Comment: Worked for me, but I also had to change how I implemented the data so I changed it an array of objects that were called like:  `template: { name: \'modal\',  data: initialData.list["+index+"]}`